# Laravel Command argument returns keyvalue pair insted of value

Tags: php, laravel, arguments, command, key-value

I've generate Laravel artisan command by `php artisan make:command SomeCommand`. Here is the entire command class `SomeCommand`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class SomeCommand extends Command{
    protected $signature = 'Call:SomeCommand {phone="8980131488"} {name="Kiran Maniya"}';

    protected $description = 'This is a buggy Command';

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle(){
        $args = $this->arguments();
        $this->info($args['phone'].' '.$args['name']);
    }
}
```

The issue is, when i call the command by `php artisan Call:SomeCommand phone="8980151878" name="Anubhav Rane"`. It outputs the arguments with keypair value as `name=Anubhav Rane` & `phone=8980151878`. It should only output the values.
I also tried catching single values by `$this->argument('phone')` and `$this->argument('name')` but still it outputs the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you're passing the arguments is incorrect. Try this:

```
php artisan Call:SomeCommand 8980151878 'Anubhav Rane'
```